Getting a two column post page in Ghost, how should i approach?
I am just familiarizing myself with Ghost, handlebars and such. I run into a problem, where i could code to show my relating tags, but i cant figure out how could i make my post.hbs to show the related post in a column next to content.  My post.hbs looks like below, and i would appriciate any comprehensive guide or help from you writing code to achive my goal. You can visualise what exactly i would like to achive on this link on 404media.co. Thanks in advance!
{{!< default}}
{{!-- The tag above means: insert everything in this file into the body of the default.hbs template --}}

{{#post}}

<main class="gh-main">

    <article class="gh-article {{post_class}}">

        <header class="gh-article-header gh-canvas">

            {{#if primary_tag}}
                <a class="gh-article-tag" href="{{primary_tag.url}}">{{primary_tag.name}}</a>
            {{/if}}
            <h1 class="gh-article-title is-title">{{title}}</h1>
            {{#if custom_excerpt}}
                <p class="gh-article-excerpt is-body">{{custom_excerpt}}</p>
            {{/if}}

            {{#if @custom.show_post_metadata}}
            <div class="gh-article-meta">
                <div class="gh-article-author-image">
                    {{#foreach authors}}
                        {{#if profile_image}}
                            <a href="{{url}}">
                                <img class="author-profile-image" src="{{img_url profile_image size="xs"}}" alt="{{name}}" />
                            </a>
                        {{else}}
                            <a href="{{url}}">{{> "icons/avatar"}}</a>
                        {{/if}}
                    {{/foreach}}
                </div>
                <div class="gh-article-meta-wrapper">
                    <h4 class="gh-article-author-name">{{authors}}</h4>
                    <div class="gh-article-meta-content">
                        <time class="gh-article-meta-date" datetime="{{date format="YYYY-MM-DD"}}">{{date}}</time>
                        {{#if reading_time}}
                            <span class="gh-article-meta-length"><span class="bull">—</span> {{reading_time}}</span>
                        {{/if}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{/if}}

            {{> "feature-image"}}

        </header>

        <section class="gh-content gh-canvas is-body{{#if @custom.enable_drop_caps_on_posts}} drop-cap{{/if}}">
            {{content}}
        </section>

    </article>

    {{#if comments}}
        <div class="gh-comments gh-canvas">
            {{comments}}
        </div>
    {{/if}}

</main>



{{/post}}

{{#if @custom.show_related_articles}}
    {{#get "posts" include="tags,authors" filter="tags:[{{post.tags.[0].slug}}]+id:-{{post.id}}" limit="4" as |related_posts|}}
        {{#if related_posts}}
            <aside class="gh-container is-grid gh-outer">
                <div class="gh-container-inner gh-inner">
                    <a class="gh-article-tag" href="{{related_posts.[0].tags.[0].url}}"><h2 class="gh-container-title">{{related_posts.[0].tags.[0].name}}</h2></a>
                    <div class="gh-feed">
                        {{#foreach related_posts}}
                            {{> "post-card" lazyLoad=true}}
                        {{/foreach}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </aside>
        {{/if}}
    {{/get}}
{{/if}}

I tried adding grid components before, like seen on https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp but i couldn't figure out for my life, how could i integrate the code into mine existing source theme example.
